# Improving performance of fuzzy string matching against a dictionary

Tags: java, data-structures

So I'm currently working for with using [SecondString](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/) for fuzzy string matching, where I have a large dictionary to compare to (with each entry in the dictionary has an associated non-unique identifier). I am currently using a hashMap to store this dictionary.

When I want to do fuzzy string matching, I first check to see if the string is in the hashMap and then I iterate through all of the other potential keys, calculating the string similarity and storing the k,v pair/s with the highest similarity. Depending on which dictionary I am using this can take a long time ( 12330 - 1800035 entries ). Is there any way to speed this up or make it faster? I am currently writing a memoization function/table as a way of speeding this up, but can anyone else think of a better way to improve the speed of this? Maybe a different structure or something else I'm missing.

Many thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: Being a technical question, this belongs to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What your looking for is a BKTree (BK-Tree) combined with the Levenshtein Distance algorithm.  The lookup performance in a BKtree depends on how "Fuzzy" your search is.  Where fuzzy is defined as the number of distance (edits) between the search word and the matches.

Here is a good blog on the subject:
http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees

Some notes on the performance:
http://www.kafsemo.org/2010/08/03_bk-tree-performance-notes.html

Notes on the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance algorithm.

Also, here is a BK-Tree written in Java.  Should give you an idea of the interface: http://code.google.com/p/java-bk-tree/

Answer (score 2):

Or you may also use a Java Fuzzy HashMap (an extention to java hashMap that allows fuzzy search): http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuzzyhashmap/ I think it is exactly what you need. Here you have a complete description of the data structure: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5565628

Comment: One thing to note about this- it won't return anything if the search key is fewer than 5 characters. You can modify the source, but there's a comment that says it had poor accuracy during testing for keys fewer than 5 letters.

Comment: Also, whereas the BK-tree will return a list of close matches, FuzzyHashMap only returns one fuzzy match. Again, this could be fixed pretty easily I think.

Answer (score 1):

see this excellent article for explanation and comparison of different fuzzy string matching: 
http://ntz-develop.blogspot.com/2011/03/fuzzy-string-search.html

java source code available at
https://code.google.com/p/fuzzy-search-tools/