# Most efficient way/library to detect predefined keywords in billions of lines?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, string-matching, fuzzy-search

Let's say I have a few billion lines of text, and a few million "keyword"s. The task is to go through these lines and see which line contains which keywords. In other words, given a map of  `(K1 -> V1)` and `(K2 -> V2)`, create a map of `(K2 -> K1)` where `K1=lineID`, `V1=text`, `K2=keywordID` and `V2=keyword`. Note also that:

- All text/keywords are English
- Text (V1) may contain spelling mistakes.
- Most keywords (V2) are single words, but some keywords may consist of more than one English word (e.g. "clean towel")

So far my initial idea to solve this is as follows:

```
1) Chop up all my keywords into single words and 
   create a large set of single words (K3)
2) Construct a BK-Tree out of these chopped up keywords,
   using Levenshtein distance
3) For each line of data (V1), 
    3.1) Chop up the text (V1) into words
    3.2) For each said word,
        3.2.1) Retrieve words (K3) from the BK-Tree that
               are close enough to said word
    3.3) Since at this point we still have false positives,
        (e.g. we would have matched "clean" from "clean water" against
         keyword "clean towel"), we check all possible combination
          using a trie of keyword (V2) to filter such false 
          positives out. We construct this trie so that at the
          end of an successful match, the keywordID (K2) can be retrieved.
    3.4) Return the correct set of keywordID (K2) for this line (V1)!
4) Profit!
```

**My questions**

- Is this a good approach? Efficiency is very important -- are there any better ways? Anything to improve?
- Are there any libraries I could use? Preferably something that would work well with Java.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945829/improving-performance-of-fuzzy-string-matching-against-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

there are some optimised multi pattern / 2D searching algorithms. don't invent the wheel again. you should also think about distributing your computation. maybe hadoop and map/reduce?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but what you are expecting here (K2->K1) is very similar to inverted index (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

I believe Lucene/Solr uses same algorithms while indexing data (it also does pre data analyze/tokenize), you might need to figure out a way you can read Lucene built indexes (start with "IndexReader" javadoc for Lucene).

While indexing your data consider each line as one document in Lucene index, create two fields in your indexes 1) line ID and 2) data - once you index all documents(lines) you already have K2->K1 created for you, you just need to find a way to parse it.

I am not sure what are your next steps after creating K2->K1, if its faster lookup than you dont need to parse your indexes you can just fire Lucene queries.

In SOLR you can also generated faceted search results on indexes, if it helps.

**EDIT:**
you can use LUKE tool for analyzing Lucene indexes (https://code.google.com/p/luke/)